Can getting an online masters degree in business grant me the ability to work as a TA in UK
My fiance is in business and we will soon be moving to the UK... would getting an Online masters in her field grant her the ability to work as a TA in universities?

Your partner would probably be technically qualified for TA positions, however, some things to realise about TA positions in the UK:

Most classes in the UK don't use TAs, consquently there are fewer TA positions that there would be in somewhere like the US.
Where TAs are used, the are usually mostly recruited from the Graduate student population at the university, rather than the public at large.

